# How to resolve specific fields.E304 error

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm learning to create custom user form on django and the procedure is still not very clear to me. So, I'm following a tutorial. However, when I try to make migrations I encounter the follow error, but the instructor's code program worked. I don't understand why mine is throwing back an error message. Please I need some clarification. I checked the answer to similar question online but I couldn't identify my mistake

```
model.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ 
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)


        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')


        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email adresss'))
        email = self.normalze_email(email)
        user = self.mode(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class UserBase(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = CountryField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    #User status
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['email']
    USERNAME_FIELD = ['last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

And the error I'm getting is shown below

```
ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'users.UserBase.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'users.UserBase.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'users.UserBase.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'users.UserBase.user_permissions'.
users.UserBase.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'users.UserBase.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'users.UserBase.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
users.UserBase.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'users.UserBase.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.      
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'users.UserBase.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
```

Comment: Did you set the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: I just add it as follows: `AUTH_USER_MODEL: 'users.CustomAccountManager`. But after adding it I encountered another error: `improperly configured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.CustomAccountManager' that has not been installed.` But I have already added the name of my app`users` to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings. py. Please what could be responsible for this resent error I just encountered.

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL: 'users.CustomAccountManager'`? A `:` and a `=` are not the same thing. It is supposed to be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomAccountManager'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between `: and =` I have corrected it but I'm still having the same error. I'm still getting improperly configured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.CustomAccountManager' that has not been installed

Comment: In fact `'users.CustomAccountManager'`? The setting is supposed to point to the model and not the manager, it should be `'users.UserBase'`